# Combobox scrollviewer.panning missing in C# code?

Tags: wpf, combobox, scrollviewer

I was wondering if there is scrollviewer.panning for the combobox in C# code.

The following xaml code:

```
<ComboBox ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" />
```

works but how do I create a new combobox in C# code with the following properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ScrollViewer sv = comboBox.Template.FindName("DropDownScrollViewer", comboBox) as ScrollViewer;
sv.PanningMode = PanningMode.Both;
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442614/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-scrollviewer-inside-a-combobox-in-wpf) question.